# context menu not working in my ag-grid

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid

My goal is show context menu when right click into cell.

But my code does not response to right click.
I could not find where I did mistake.

Below is my code. 
I wrote the log "console.log("getContentMenuItems()");"  but this log was not printed.

my-grid-application.component.ts

```
export class MyGridApplicationComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  gridOptions: GridOptions;
  private subscription: Subscription;
  private isPubPark: boolean = false; 
  private getContextMenuItems;

  constructor(private commCodeGridOptionService: CommCodeGridOptionService, private commonService: CommonService) { 
    console.log("MyGridApplicationComponent: Constructor()");

    let params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search.substring(1)); 
    this.isPubPark = (params.get('isPubPark') == 'true');
    console.log("params:" + params + ", " + params.get('isPubPark') + ", isPubPark: " + this.isPubPark);

    this.commCodeGridOptionService.setTarget(this.isPubPark);
    this.commCodeGridOptionService.fetchColumnDefs();
    this.commCodeGridOptionService.getColumnDefMessage().subscribe(message => {
      console.log("MyGridApplicationComponent:getColumnDefMessage()");
      this.gridOptions.columnDefs = this.commCodeGridOptionService.gridOptions.columnDefs;
      this.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(this.gridOptions.columnDefs);      
    });

    this.commCodeGridOptionService.getRowDataMessage().subscribe(message => { 
      console.log("MyGridApplicationComponent getRowDataMessage().subscribe()");

      this.gridOptions.rowData = this.commCodeGridOptionService.commcodeSitesList;

      //The gridOptions api will be set and ready to use once the grid's gridReady event has been called.
      this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.gridOptions.rowData);
    });

    this.getContextMenuItems = function getContextMenuItems(params) {
      console.log("getContentMenuItems()");
      var result = [
        {
          name: "Always Disabled",
          disabled: true,
          tooltip: "Very long tooltip, did I mention that I am very long, well I am! Long!  Very Long!"
        },
        "separator",
        "copy"
      ];
      return result;
    };
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("MyGridApplicationComponent: ngOnInit()");
    this.gridOptions = {};

    this.subscription = this.commonService.notifyObservable$.subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      if (res.hasOwnProperty('option') && res.option === 'onCommCodeSelected') {
        this.changeCommCodeFilter(res.value);
      }
    });
  }

  //set filter to commcode when click commCodeDesc component
  public changeCommCodeFilter(commcode: string) {
    console.log("changeCommCodeFilter() ", commcode);

    let ageFilterComponent = this.gridOptions.api.getFilterInstance('commCode');
    ageFilterComponent.setModel({
        type: 'equals',
        filter: commcode,
        filterTo: null
    });
    this.gridOptions.api.onFilterChanged();
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

my-grid-application.component.html

```
<h3><a href='/?isPubPark={{!isPubPark}}'></a></h3>
<app-comm-code-selectbox></app-comm-code-selectbox>
<div style="width: 100%; height:700px">
  <ag-grid-angular #agGrid 
      style="width:100%;height:100%;" 
      class="ag-fresh" 
      [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
      [enableRangeSelection]="true"
      [allowContextMenuWithControlKey]="true"
      [getContextMenuItems]="getContextMenuItems"
      rowHeight=100
      enableSort 
      enableFilter
      enableColResize>
  </ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Context menu is separate enterprise functionality so it needs to be installed separately:

```
npm install ag-grid-enterprise
```

And you must include it in the module after you imported ag grid for angular, like so:

```
import { AgGridModule } from 'ag-grid-angular'; 
import'ag-grid-enterprise';
```

It will work now!

Answer (score 3):

You must install the menu module from ag-grid enterprise:

```
npm install @ag-grid-enterprise/menu
```

use the module in your component:

```
import { MenuModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/menu';
```

configure your grid to use this module:

in .ts:

```
gridModules = [MenuModule, ...];
```

in template:

```
<ag-grid-angular [modules]="gridModules" ...
```

You might also have to set `suppressContextMenu = false;` and implement the `getContextMenuItems` function

Answer (score 2):

For React,

1. Make sure you have installed the `menu` package from `ag-grid enterprise`

```
npm install @ag-grid-enterprise/menu
```

2. Add `getContextMenuItems` method as mentioned in [ag-grid docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/context-menu/).
3. Add following attributes in ag-grid's instance.

```
suppressContextMenu={false}
allowContextMenuWithControlKey={true}
getContextMenuItems={getContextMenuItems}
```